# ID-Selector in combination with Class-Selector not working

Tags: css

I'm not able to use an ID-selctor in combination with a class-selector. It baffles me as I also used a CSS Validator to check for erors. So, why is only the latter working in my code?

This is my Code:

```css
#result .red1 {
 color: #FF0000;
}

.red2 {
 color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<span id="result" class="red1">Test of Color</span>
<br>
<span id="result" class="red2">Test of Color</span>
```

Comment: _“It baffles me as I also used a CSS Validator to check for erors”_ - just because something is _syntactically_ correct, doesn’t necessarily mean it also _means_ what you want it to. The “space” means you are trying to select elements with the class `red1` that are _descendants_ of the element with id `result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between the ID and the class selector

```
#result.red1 {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

"#result .red1" means find the class red1 INSIDE the result element.
It is better not to use ID as CSS selectors though.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong. You have the id and the class on the same element.

You should not put a space, like this: #result.red1

The space means that the element that has class red1 must be a descendant of an element with id result.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because you put a space between `#result` and `red1`.

```css
#result.red1 {
 color: #FF0000;
}

.red2 {
 color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<span id="result" class="red1">Test of Color</span>
<br>
<span id="result" class="red2">Test of Color</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

To use combination of `class` with `id` remove the space. Also don't use duplicate `id`.

```css
#result.red1 {
 color: #FF0000;
}

.red2 {
 color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<span id="result" class="red1">Test of Color</span>
<br>
<span id="result" class="red2">Test of Color</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

> `#result .red1` selects all elements with class `red1` inside element with id `result`.

*For example :*

```
<span id="result">
  <span class="red1">Selected</span>
</span>
```

> `#result.red1` selects element that have id `result` and class `red1`.

*For example : your case.*

**So, for fix your problem, remove the space between the `#result` and the `.red1`**

```
#result.red1 {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```css
 #result.red1 {
  color: #FF0000;
}

.red2 {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<span id="result" class="red1">Test of Color</span>
<br>
<span id="result" class="red2">Test of Color</span>
```

Comment: `#result .red1` matches all descendants with the class `red1`. `#result > .red1` would only matche the children with class `red1`.

Comment: @t.niese `#result > .red1` selects elements with class `red` that is direct children result.

Comment: The term children in css or the html dom api is always only used for direct children.

Answer (score 1):

Note that spaces have a special semantic in CSS selectors. The way you wrote it says "look for an element with `id="result"`, with an element of `class="red1"` inside (see the third "Test of Color" line below).

If you want both selectors to refer to the same element, you have to omit the space, i.e. write `#result.red1` or `.red1#result`.

Also, do not use duplicate IDs in the html code.

```css
#result1.red1 {
 color: #FF0000;
}

.red2 {
 color: #FF6600;
}

#result3 .red3 {
 color: #FF0066;
}
```

```html
<span id="result1" class="red1">Test of Color</span>
<br>
<span id="result2" class="red2">Test of Color</span>
<br>
<span id="result3"><span class="red3">Test of Color</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#result.red1 {
 color: #FF0000;
}

.red2 {
 color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<span id="result" class="red1">Test of Color</span>
<br>
<span id="result" class="red2">Test of Color</span>
```